# Send camera image to cloud for more open streaming?

Tags: raspbian, video, webcam

What I'm looking for: I have a Pi with a Pi-Cam. I want to be able to plug it in at work, or in a hotel room and have it upload what its seeing to a server that I can then connect to from anywhere.

While there have been some good tutorials, every one of them involves setting up the webserver locally, on the Pi, but I want to be able to connect in places where a firewall or something of that ilk would prevent me from connecting directly to the Pi's server.

Is this possible?

Comment: Would uploading slow-interval to dropbox be sufficient? Then I can provide some script (I guess 1fps max)

Comment: I have box.com working with davfs. You can just mount the box directory and make your server save the images in there. I'm pretty sure it's just as easy to do with Dropbox or any other cloud services. Keyword is "davfs" and your prefered cloud service

Answer (score 1):

Install Hamachi, [perhaps using this method](http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=5207) to bypass the internal firewalls that are in place. Hamachi will put you in a virtual private network (VPN) and you can let your other PC's join this network as well. This should allow the possibility of running **and connecting to** a webserver - or any other method you prefer such SSH'ing or port-forwarding.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest to use Bittorent Sync on your RPI and on one (or more) of your other computers at home, ie another RPI, a laptop or a PC.

It's pretty straightforward, free and apparently (btsync is closed source) secure to do so.

1) Install on RPI
Download .tar.gz directly from bittorent.com or use an unofficial repository:
add-apt-repository ppa:tuxpoldo/btsync
apt-get update
apt-get install btsync

2) Install btsync on *any* other internet-connected device, ie tablet, phone, windows, linux, mac using official downloads. You can install on more than 2 devices to keep files on all of them on sync, but 2 is minimum.

3) Configure a folder with webcam pictures on RPI to be synced via BTsync. Typically this means copying a secret folder hash from RPI to other devices with BTsync you want to sync to. You'd can send an email, copy paste or use a QR code to copy folder hash.
All devices you configured with hash will receive the folder with pictures automatically with no additional actions needed.

Few examples and more info:
http://blog.bittorrent.com/2013/08/20/sync-hacks-how-to-sync-without-data-loss-using-btsync-raspberry-pi/
http://jack.minardi.org/raspberry_pi/replace-dropbox-with-bittorrent-sync-and-a-raspberry-pi/

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. If you could include the important info from the link it would make your answer more useful and help keep this site/Q:A more useful in the future, as including this info protects against link rot.

Comment: Setting up Bittorent Sync will be very specific to one's environment. My answer points to Bittorent Sync as a possible option to syncronize webcam pictures with links for more info on the subject.

Comment: Yes, but it is still all using a Pi, so relatively little will be different, aside from the software installed/the OS. All of it will be on a Raspberry Pi, so you can still post the essential parts. If the OP can't figure out a part, he can comment/ask a new question or Google it. Please don't feel I am picking on you, I'm not. I'm simply doing my duty as a member of Stack Exchange and moderating the q's/a's as best I can, and that involves showing the correct path to take in regards to answers.

Comment: Hope my last edit makes sense, thanks for comments!

Comment: Yes, much better. I understand now. Glad we've sorted this out :)

Answer (score 0):

Dropbox is on its way to the raspberry pi, but not yet fully developed.

Therefore i would suggest using google drive. There are several ways to get google play working, one of them are an application called grive.

If you follow [this link](http://raspberrywebserver.com/serveradmin/back-up-your-pi-to-your-google-drive.html) you can read more how to set up grive on your raspberry.